# Can I browse Mono source code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mono

I'd like to see how some classes are implemented in Mono and would like to use code navigation features found in Visual Studio. Has anyone tried importing Mono source codes as a VS project / solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is fairly simple. The solution file for Visual Studio 2008 is shipped with a source tarball and is located under the **..\mono-2.6.1.tar\mono-2.6.1\mono-2.6.1\msvc** directory (you should specify your mono version of course). Here is a quotation from a readme file:

> BUILDING
>
> From this directory type:
>
> ```
>    msbuild.exe mono.sln /p:Configuration=Debug_eglib
> ```
>
> msbuild must be in your path, it comes with the .NET Framework.

Latest sources can be downloaded from [here](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/).

**EDIT**

First of all, mono class library is part of a mono runtime and is being build simultaneously with a runtime. Not all parts of mono (as well as not all parts of a base class library) are written in c#. For example, zlib related stuff is written in C. Building mono is not an easy process, my answer above is just a tip as to where the solution file is located. The complete tutorial on building mono on Windows cold be found [here](http://shana.worldofcoding.com/en/mono_cygwin_tutorial.html). If you just want to browse a source code, *..\mono-2.6.1.tar\mono-2.6.1\mono-2.6.1\mcs\class\corlib\System* would be a good starting point.

Comment: Isn't this a solution file for compilers etc? My VS doesn't have C++ component installed and it doesn't seem to be able to open a single project in that solution (I expected the sources to be C#, not C++ for the class library).